# Two tables vertically align

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

i have two tables, each of them has 4 columns. one is just below the other. i want to know how to make every column of the below table have same width of the column of the above table. it looks like this:

```
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|       |       |       |       |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|       |       |       |       |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|       |       |       |       |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
```

some space lines are here.

```
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|       |       |       |       |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|       |       |       |       |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
```

adding one more `hline` will make one table `septable`, which it looks like two tables with good vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Item-No.} & \textbf{name} & \textbf{cross section} & \textbf{grade}\\
\hline
\textbf{W1} & Z-column & HN350x175 -- 346x174 & Q235\\
\hline
\textbf{W17} & Horiz. support transversal hoist beam & HW100x100 & Q235\\
\hline
\hline
\textbf{P11} & longitudinal hoist beam & HN300x150 -- 300x150 & Q235\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

but one more thing, how to add `vertical spacing` between the tables?

Comment: The simplest thing would be to put the text between them into a `\multicolumn{4}{l}`. Would this be OK for your document?

Comment: Or simply use fixed width columns?

Comment: @Martin: there is no text between the two tables, just several space lines. i have added an example in the original text. now it looked like two tables. but i don't know how to add vertical space between them.

Comment: @Alan: the tex source code is generated from a C program. in the programming status, i don't know how i can find a appropriate column width for every column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to add some vertical space between the two logical tables while having the same column width is to only use one real table and add the vertical white space as `\multicolumn` row which includes a `\vspace` to make it as high as required. Note that the `\multicolumn` is required to disable the vertical borders in the normal cells. Without this a simple empty cell with `\vspace` would be enough.

You can adjust the white space with the argument of `\vspace{<distance>}`. The value wont be the exact distance because the cell `\strut` is also in effect, which adds also a certain depth. If you need exact distances you have to calculate this in.

#### Example Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Item-No.} & \textbf{name} & \textbf{cross section} & \textbf{grade}\\
\hline
\textbf{W1} & Z-column & HN350x175 -- 346x174 & Q235\\
\hline
\textbf{W17} & Horiz. support transversal hoist beam & HW100x100 & Q235\\
\hline
%
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\vspace{1cm}}\\
%
\hline
\textbf{P11} & longitudinal hoist beam & HN300x150 -- 300x150 & Q235\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: "…`\multicolumn` is required…" You could also use:  `\noalign{\bigskip}` (or some other vskip)

Comment: @morbusg: Good idea. I meant something like "use `\multicolumn` instead of ``\\\hline\vspace{..}\\``" to avoid the vertical cell border.

Comment: @Martin: Ah, I see, makes sense. However, with `\noalign`, I believe you wouldn't need to worry about the `\strut`?

Comment: @morbusg: Yes, `\noalign` would be better in this specific case (I simply didn't think about it). However, I think beginners would understand `\multicolumn` easier. Also it can also be used if some text between the tables should be added.

Comment: @Martin: thank you for your good and clear explanation. i have used `\multicolumn` in my table. but i didn't think out in this way to add vertical spacing.

Comment: @Martin, @morbusg: how to use `\noalign{\bigskip}` in this case? i meaning `disabling the vertical borders in cells`. according to morbusg's meaning (maybe i misunderstood), replaced `\multicolumn` with `\noalign{\bigskip}`. but it isn't what i mean.