# Add vertical space between two tables in a single figure

Tags: tables, floats, vertical-alignment

Similar to [this SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13733/two-tables-vertically-align) but without the requirement that the tables be the same width:

I have one figure containing two `tabular` environments:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rlrrrr}
        \textbf{sector\_flows} \\
        \toprule
        a & b & c & d & e & f \\
        \midrule
        1 & Foo & 1995 & 1 & 1 & 3107 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{12cm}
    \begin{tabular}{rlll}
        \textbf{sectors} \\
        \toprule
        g & h & i & j \\
        \midrule
        1 & Foo & Bar & Baz  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Relational database format for storing input-output flow data}
    \label{fig:db_format_for_io}
\end{figure}
```

But the `\vspace` doesn't put any space between the tables. Instead it puts space between the tables and the caption.

Why doesn't this work, and how can I achieve vertical space between two tables in a single figure?

Comment: try `\vspace*{}`

Comment: `\vspace*{}` has the same problem.

Comment: Add a blank line before `\vspace`

Comment: @egreg That's the answer! Please post this as a solution and I'll accept. (Anything in the way of explanation would be gratefully received too!)

Comment: @LondonRob It's a duplicate: the question I linked to deals exactly with the same problem. Please, upvote David's answer there, he's in desperate need of rep. `;-)`

Comment: try\hspace{0.5cm} between two tabular environment within one figure environment