# Stacking tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, tabularx

Is it possible to stack two tabulars within a table? For example, get something like

[image]

with a single caption. I tried using `\quad`, as the case of `figure`, but with no success. Any ideas? Also, using `\centering` does not result in what I want.

Comment: Well, yes, but it's not `\quad`you should use (it is a horizontal spacing). Use `\vskip 1em` after the upper table instead.

Comment: Kind of similar to [floats - Add vertical space between two tables in a single figure - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200184/add-vertical-space-between-two-tables-in-a-single-figure?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: tabular are positioned by the same code as letters. so just leave a blank line and they will be in separate paragraphs (same as `\includegraphics` in a `figure`)